# Neo4j Pattern Comprehension failing with path condition in where clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j 3.4 and am struggling with this particular query

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:IS_A_MEMBER_OF]->(c:Church)
RETURN size([(p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(:User)-[:IS_A_MEMBER_OF]->(c) WHERE NOT (u)-[:ACKNOWLEDGED|POSTED]->(p) | p])
```

This query is designed to get the number of posts for the given Church that a user has not yet acknowledged and did not post themselves.  In other words, it should retrieve all the posts by members of the church, then figure out which ones the user `u` has neither acknowledged or posted and return the count.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out why Neo4j is not doing the check in the where clause.  Is there something about pattern comprehensions that I am missing?  Because the number returned is the same for all users, no matter whether they have acknowledged or posted any of the posts.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a query to create a sample graph where we can recreate what you're seeing?

Comment: Yes, this should work

```CREATE (c:Church),
    (u:User)-[:IS_A_MEMBER_OF]->(c),
    (m:User)-[:IS_A_MEMBER_OF]->(c),
       (e:User)-[:IS_A_MEMBER_OF]->(c),
       (u)-[:POSTED]->(x:Post),
       (u)-[:POSTED]->(y:Post),
       (m)-[:POSTED]->(z:Post),
       (e)-[:ACKNOWLEDGED]->(y)```

Comment: Thank you, I can replicate this on nearly every version. I'll forward this along to the Cypher team to analyze. I can provide a workaround query if needed.

Comment: It's interesting that if you remove the `size` function then the returned array will be correct.

Comment: would it help to use a WITH for the comprehension and then only SIZE() in the return?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I don't think I understand what that would look like, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, I used `count` instead of `size`, `size` is for arrays and here you have a node row, `count` will aggregate all your row into a result.

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:IS_A_MEMBER_OF]->(c:Church),
      (c)<-[:IS_A_MEMBER_OF]-(:User)-[:POSTED]->(p:Post)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:ACKNOWLEDGED|POSTED]->(p)
RETURN c, u, count(p)
```

This return for every church and members of this church, a number of unacknowledged posts, not posted by the member.

Comment: Thank you Cyrbil, however, I need to accomplish this with a pattern comprehension.  In production, it is actually part of a larger query with other comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a similar bug report. This seems to be a problem starting with 3.3.6.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/11967